# Iterate over pandas dataframe rows as pure text

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, text, row

I would like to read a dataframe (which contains tweets) row by row in order to analyze the text.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tweets2.csv')
df.head()

for row in df.iterrows():
    print (row)
```

This code I wrote does not do the job, since the "row" also includes the index. Instead, I want the simple text, that I will process further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `df.values`:

```
for row in df.values:
    print(row)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Col2' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

print(df)

   Col1 Col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
4     5    e

for row in df.values:
    print(row)

[1 'a']
[2 'b']
[3 'c']
[4 'd']
[5 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the job!

Answer (score 0):

[`iterrows` yields `(index, Series)` pairs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

So you could unpack them in the for loop:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

If you don't use the `i`, you should change it to `_`.

Using `iterrows`, each `row` is a `Series`. As shown by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, an alternative is using `values`:

```
for row in df.values:
    print(row)
```

With this method each `row` is a `numpy` array (so labeling is lost).